# I can't connect to my WiFi network

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a problem with my notebook, I can't connect to a WiFi network from my notebook.

It finds all the wireless networks around but it is unable to connect to anyone. I've tried deleting the password of the network and trying to connect without password but it didn't work either. I know that my WiFi network is working because I can connect to it from my smartphone. I also tried pinging 127.0.0.1 and I received the reply. I don't know what to do to make it works, is there something wrong with my network card? I also tried it on Linux and faced the same problem.

Comment: What happens when you try to connect? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Was it working before and suddenly stopped working?

Comment: I don't get an error message, it only say: please wait while windows connects to the network... and in about 30 seconds the message disappears and nothing happens.

Comment: Not suddenly... One day I turned on the computer and it didn't connect

Comment: When you say 'connect', do you mean connect to the network itself, or in regard to internet access? FYI: Pinging 127.0.01 should work in most cases because that is an address for your computer (localhost).

Comment: We need more information to diagnose your issue. Are you getting an IP address? Does your router/access point support DHCP? What do you have configured for your DNS IP addresses? Etc.

Comment: Thanks to all for answer, but the problem was apparently solved just by clicking on the repair connection option, which reset the wireless adapter and get the ip again. The problem now is that I have to repair my connection every time I turn on my pc. I don't know why I have to do that... every thing seems to be all right  before reseting my connection (I'm connected to the wireless network, I'm getting an IP address, DNSs, my router support DHCP, and apparently I'm connected but I can't access internet). iglvx: Pinging 127.0.0.1 test if my network card works, at least that's what I read

Answer (score 1):

First, check if you have the correct drivers for your network device. If not, try searching your card manufacturer's website for correct drivers.

The card not working in Linux is interesting. Your card may have some physical options (buttons or switches on the side of your notebook), or it may have firmware settings that are not controlled by the OS. Look on your card manufacturer's website and see if there is a way to change those settings if this applies to your model.

If you are still covered by warranty, send it in for replacement/repair. The makers of your card usually know how to fix things.

If all else fails, your card might be broken and needs replacement. Before you get it replaced, check if it is broken in the first place. Find a store that can figure out if it needs repairing or not.